# How do I return a specific HTTP response (coming from a site A) through a site B to a user’s browser?

Tags: http, browser, request, cross-domain, response

I want to do the following:

- Site A sends an HTTP request to site B;
- Site A stores the HTTP response coming from site B;
- Site A resends exactly this HTTP response to a user connected on its page.

As if site A redirected its user to site B. The only difference is that **I don’t want to use any function specifically made for redirection** (as ‘header('Location: siteb.com’);’ in php or ‘window.location.href = siteb.com’ in js), because the request must first go through the site A.

Knowing that **I own the site A** (both frontend and backend) **but not site B** (neither frontend nor backend).

How could I possibly implement that? Are there any existing techniques? If not, is there any innovative way to do so?

Thanks for considering my question. I took a long time searching for any related posts, but I couldn’t find exactly this scenario.